# Imprimir resultado de funcion JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente función lo que hace es tomar informacion de una impresora ,codigo suministrado por su fabricante , el tema es que necesito imprimir "SerialNumber","hostName","productNumber","firmwareVersion" ,me dicen que mediante la funcion Onclick, pero no logro hacerlo por ello pido su ayuda si alguien puede ayudarme gracias.
main.js

```
function getManufacturerInfo()
{
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
oxpddiscovery.GetOXPdDiscoveryTree()
    .then(function(discoveryTree)
    {
        try
        { 
            oxpddeviceinfo.Setup(discoveryTree);
            oxpddeviceinfo.GetManufacturerInfo()
                .then(function(deviceinfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        oxpddeviceinfo.GetManufacturerInfo();
                        dfd.resolve(); 
                        document.getElementById("SerialNumber").innerHTML = deviceinfo.deviceSerialNumber;
                        document.getElementById("hostName").innerHTML = deviceinfo.hostName;
                        document.getElementById("firmwareVersion").innerHTML = deviceinfo.firmwareVersion;
                        document.getElementById("productNumber").innerHTML = deviceinfo.productNumber;

                    }
                    window.onload=
                    catch(err)
                    {
                        console.log('ManufacturerInfo: ' + 'err.name="' + err.name + '", ' + 'err.message="' + err.message);
                        dfd.reject(err);
                    }
                }
                ); 
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log('DiscoveryTree: ' + 'err.name="' + err.name + '", ' + 'err.message="' + err.message);
            dfd.reject(err);
        }
    } 
    );
return dfd.promise();  
};
```

Comment: Necesitas un evento para ejecutar esa función. Por ejemplo cuando cargue el DOM, cuando bajes la rueda del ratón o cómo te dijeron, cuando des un click en algo. Me llama la atención que estés asignando el error de una promesa al  `window.onload`. Tienes más código?

Comment: El codigo fue suminisrado no lo cree yo ,para generar el evento  lo intente con un button <input class="button" type="button" value="Descubrir" onclick="getManufacturerInfo(deviceinfo(document.write("deviceinfo.hostName")))"/>        pero no tengo exito ,solo quiero imprimirlo en pantalla